# 2 iPhones, 2 Computers on LAN, how to share Apps?

Tags: itunes, iphone

I had an iPhone 3G, and my girlfriend and I constantly play games on it.
When then the 3GS came out, I bought one with the intention of giving my girlfriend the 3G to use as a Touch (without SIM card), so she could play games any time, and so that I could have my phone back ;)

I think I have it running now, but of course the apps she's used to are all on my iTunes (Mac) and her iTunes is empty (PC).

Is there a way that she can have access to the apps (on my iTunes), which we co-paid for?

Also, if the solution involves sharing an iTunes account between my Mac and her PC, is there a way to make it so that our genius recommendations remain distinct? Our music tastes are not similar, so I don't want to receive her music & app recommendations.

Help me Obi-Wan(s), you're my only hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install iTunes 9. It has [a new feature called Home Sharing](http://www.apple.com/itunes/whats-new/#home-sharing) that'll let you share applications among up to five computers on a network.

Comment: I thought Home Sharing was only for music & videos. Are you sure it does applications? I don't see them mentioned on the page you link to.

Comment: Yes, it does also work for apps.

Comment: Here is a link to the article that really explains it: http://www.macworld.com/article/142729/2009/09/homesharing.html